# In Google App Engine, what is the difference between Model.get(key) and Model.get_by_key_name(key_names)?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Does get(key) require the entity key and get_by_key_name(key_names) require the key_name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a difference.  An Entity in the datastore is identified by a combination of its Kind, its parent, and its identifier. ([link](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keysandentitygroups.html#Paths_and_Key_Uniqueness)) The "identifier" can either be a number or a string.  A Key object contains both the identifier and the parent information.  So when you call get(), there is just one argument - the Key object.  When you call get_by_key_name, notice that there are 2 arguments - one is the key_name, one is the parent.

So a Key is an object with several parts, whereas a key name is just a string.  To make things more confusing, a Key object can be encoded as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is official explanation for [get()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get) and this one is for [get_by_key_name()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_by_key_name)
I hope this helps.

Comment: yeah, I've actually read over those documentations...I was pretty sure that "key" and "key name" were two separate things, but wanted to be sure.  So...are they different?